# How to join together all the elements in an IEnumerable of IEnumerables?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

Just in case you're wondering how this came up, I'm working with some resultsets from Entity Framework.

I have an object that is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`; basically, a list of lists of strings.

I want to merge all the lists of strings into one big list of strings.

What is the best way to do this in C#.net?

Comment: [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb534336.aspx)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the LINQ SelectMany method:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> myOuterList = // some IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>...
IEnumerable<String> allMyStrings = myOuterList.SelectMany(sl => sl);
```

To be very clear about what's going on here (since I hate the thought of people thinking this is some kind of sorcery, and I feel bad that some other folks deleted the same answer):

[SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) ( a static method that through syntactic sugar looks like an instance method on a specific type) on `IEnumerable<T>`.  It takes your original enumeration of enumerations and a function for converting each item of that into a enumeration.

Because the items are *already* enumerations, the conversion function is simple- just return the input (`sl => sl` means "take a paremeter named `sl` and return it").  SelectMany then provides an enumeration over each of these in turn, resulting in your "flattened" list..

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Concat` method:

```
firstEnumerable.Concat(secondEnumerable)
```

Using `SelectMany` will force an additional evaluation of each element of both enumerations that you don't need.