# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<long>>' to <long>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I wrote the following LINQ statement inside my ASP.NET MVC web application:

```
List<long> ids = TServers
  .Select(a => a.TVirtualMachines
     .Select(a2 => a2.Technology.ID.Value))
  .ToList();
```

What I am trying to achieve is to do the following:

we have Tservers , which have a collection of TVirtualMachines, and each TVirtualMachine is associated with on Technology. and i want to select the Technology.ID for all the TVirtualMachine what are under a Tserver. but my above code will return the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: `Tservers.SelectMany()`

Comment: what will this do exactly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join together all the elements in an IEnumerable of IEnumerables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958116/how-to-join-together-all-the-elements-in-an-ienumerable-of-ienumerables)

Comment: @johnG `SelectMany` will flatten the collections from the internal `Select` into one collection.

Answer (score 6):

You need [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
List<long> ids = 
  TServers.SelectMany(a => 
    a.TVirtualMachines.Select(a2 => a2.Technology.ID.Value)).ToList();
```